# Not getting swapfile warning anymore. shortmess=filnxtToOFA

Tags: swap-file

For the last few weeks I have noticed that neovim is not warning me when a file is already opened in another instance, like it used to. I find this useful in keeping organised and stopping me from making more tmux windows than I need to.

I have found that my `shortmess` settings are `filnxtToOFA` and `A` apparently supresses the swapfile warning. My config only has `set shortmess+=F`, so I don't know how this has happened.

I did used to get the warning and now I don't. Should `A` be in the vim/nvim default `shortmess` settings? How can I find out what has happened?

How do I remove the `A` and would that bring the warnings back?

Comment: Ähm, did you not read the documentation for 'shm'? `:h 'shm'` clearly states, that the `A` flag will hide the `ATTENTION` message for existing swapfiles. so if you do want to show it, do not add the `A` flag to your 'shm' option.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I said above that my settings only have `set shortmess+=F`, so I don't know how this has happened, hence my query.

Comment: I don't think vim does add this automatically. Just remove it then :)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt When I start `--clean` the `A` isn't there, but it is with `--noplugin`. But grepping through my config doesn't show any other `shortmess` other than the `F` addition, which seems to be there by default anyway. How do I remove the `A`? I tried `set shortmess-=A` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you try `:verbose set shm?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, that led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice from the comments led me to `:verbose set shm?`:

```
shortmess=filnxtToOFA
      Last set from ~/.local/share/vim/plugged/vim-polyglot/autoload/polyglot/init.vim line 2722
```

This plugin seems to do various things not directly related to its primary purpose. There is a setting to disable these 'sensible' options, but it doesn't seem to actually work.

This plugin is also the cause of another confusion I had where `cloud-init.yaml` files would open with the filetype `helm`. I don't know if that is correct (it doesn't seem to be and it changes the escape characters), but I didn't know why that was happening either.

Also, it seems that using the `--noplugin` switch when starting nvim still loads this plugin? That didn't help when trying to debug this problem.

Comment: I agree, setting this option (along with others inside there, (e.g. setting the encoding may actually invalidate all your string values inside the memory at this point)) is actually a bug. vim polyglot should not set those options. Most of those, should be set by the user (or specific filetype plugins)